# Racket - Map a function which takes an argument

Tags: scheme, racket

I wanna map a function which takes an argument:

```
(map best-play (cdr tree) true) ;true is the argument I wanna pass
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use a function called `curry` (or its sibling, `curryr`), which permits *partial application*, allowing you to pass in arguments without calling the function to yield a new function.

To understand that, consider this example.

```
> (define add2 (curry + 2))
> (add2 1)
3
> (add2 2)
4
```

Effectively, calling `curry` on `+` and passing a single argument creates a new function which is equivalent to this:

```
(lambda (x) (+ 2 x))
```

The function `curryr` is similar, but it passes arguments starting from the *right*, rather than the left. This is useful in functions where order matters.

```
> (define sub2 (curryr - 2))
> (sub2 4)
2
```

You can use these functions to perform the mapping you want. If the `true` argument comes second, then you'd want to use `curryr`, like this:

```
(map (curryr best-play true) (cdr tree))
```